# Zoom an Image URL to fit Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, zooming

Is it possible to use an iframe to link directly to large images without having a horizontal scroll bar or cutting off the image?

I've made an example here to show what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/yLu3acL4/1/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="iframe-holder">
       <iframe src="somelargeimageontheweb.jpg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>    
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{height:100%;}
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:80%;
  background:#CCC
}
.iframe-holder{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
.iframe-holder iframe {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

It links directly to the a .jpg URL but it's zoomed in 100% which creates 2 scroll bars. I just need the width of the image to match the width of the iframe and the height would just be dependant on images ratio.

The example I'm thinking of is when you search for a large image on google the page starts zoomed out so you can see the entire image and allows you to click to view it at 100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use an iframe to get the results you want.

Instead, you can change it to an img tag and change your CSS to this:

```
.iframe-holder{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.iframe-holder img {
  max-width:100%; 
  max-height:100%;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

Change the iframe-holder width and height to whatever you want and the image size will automatically adjust to the size of the DIV.

Comment: Ahh haha I feel so stupid now. I love getting answers like these though, I thought I was going have to do something complex to get this to work. I was using the iframe since I was loading youtube videos as well as images.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar is here because the body element inside your iframe has got non-zero margin attribute.

Possible solution is to add `marginwidth="0"` atribute to the iframe, but that IS NOT supported in HTML5 anymore (!!!).
(Example on http://jsfiddle.net/yLu3acL4/5/)

If those image would be hosted on the same domain, you could use some JS magic to achieve the same result, but on different domain that's quite impossible.